# Lost executor on simple sparksql join query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a simple sparkSQL query, where it does a match on 2 data sets each dataset is around 500GB. So whole data is around 1TB.

```
val adreqPerDeviceid = sqlContext.sql("select count(Distinct a.DeviceId) as MatchCount from adreqdata1 a inner join adreqdata2  b ON a.DeviceId=b.DeviceId ")
adreqPerDeviceid.cache()
adreqPerDeviceid.show()
```

job works fine till data loading (10k tasks assigned). 
200 tasks are assigned at `.cache` line. where it fails! i know i am not caching a huge data its just a number why does it fail over here.

Below are error details:

> at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1824)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1837)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1850)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:215)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Limit.executeCollect(basicOperators.scala:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1385)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1903)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1384)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.head(DataFrame.scala:1314)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.take(DataFrame.scala:1377)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.showString(DataFrame.scala:178)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:401)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:362)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.show(DataFrame.scala:370)  at
>   comScore.DayWiseDeviceIDMatch$.main(DayWiseDeviceIDMatch.scala:62)    at
>   comScore.DayWiseDeviceIDMatch.main(DayWiseDeviceIDMatch.scala)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:674)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
>     at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

Comment: where you are running this job? local or in cluster?

Comment: in amazon EMR cluster, it has 200GB RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you make a join on a huge dataset, i.e looking for aggregated value from the join of 2 datasets your cluster need a minimum (Dataset1+Dataset2) size of hardDisk not RAM. then the job will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely amount of unique device ids don't fit the RAM of single executor. try `spark.conf.set('spark.shuffle.partitions', 500)` to get 500 tasks instead of your current 200. If query still performs badly, double it again.

What else may get the query to work better is having the data sorted by the key you're joining.